# Linux SCHED_OTHER (CFS) User Time vs. SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO User Time

Tags: linux, scheduling

Wondering if there are any well informed Linux gurus here who can answer a question of mine. I have been doing a statistical analysis for my OS class on which scheduler is more efficient/effective for CPU and IO bound processes. One result I am getting from GNU time that I cannot explain is why identical processes running under SCHED_OTHER complete in less user time than SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO (for a CPU bound process). I thought user time would be independent of the schedule policy. Can anyone shed light or point me to a resource that can explain this (besides going through source code, its just an undergrad class).

The data I am using was gathered over multiple runs with many concurrently running CPU bound processes so the data should be fairly accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is conceivable that CPU-bound `SCHED_FIFO` real-time processes don't give other processes a chance to initiate an asynchronous read. Whereas with `SCHED_OTHER` more processes initiate asynchronous reads thus spending less total time waiting for data.

Comment: OK, we were thinking that SCHED_OTHER is probably doing some sort of opportunistic optimization under the hood, but its hard to find documentation on this stuff. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to caching effects (which regularly crop up in performance comparisons like this).

Every context switch is going to lose you a chunk of cache, as the swapped in process (and kernel) stomp all over some of your cache lines.